# How to add tree to tab in bean

Tags: jsf, tabs, tree, primefaces

I try to add tree to 1 tab:

```
Tab tmp = new Tab();
TreeNode root = new  DefaultTreeNode("root",null);
TreeNode test = new DefaultTreeNode("test",root);
tmp.getChildren().add((UIComponent)root);
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: Don't you prefer using the <p:tab <p:tree tags in xhtml page instead?

Comment: I want to have a dynamic AccordionPanel, AccordionPanel have many tab, each tab have one tree, all is dynamic ( i want to create in bean file)
can you show me the resolution :)

Comment: what version of primefacse do you use?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use [Accordion Panel - Model](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/accordionPanelModel.jsf)

> Accordion can display dynamic number of tabs backed by a model. As tabs are generated on-the-fly it is easy to implement adding/removing tabs as well.

Take a look at the example... INMO it the way you should implement your task... (much much easier , and its the way primefaces implement it in the showcase)

to expand the given example  try

adding into the tab

```
<p:tree value="#{player.root}" var="node" id="tree">  
    <p:treeNode id="treeNode">  
        <h:outputText value="#{node}" id="lblNode"/>  
    </p:treeNode>  
</p:tree>
```

and add into player class...

```
private TreeNode root;  

public initTree() {  
    root = new DefaultTreeNode("Root", null);  
    TreeNode node0 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0", root);  
    TreeNode node1 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 1", root);  
    TreeNode node2 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 2", root);  

    TreeNode node00 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.0", node0);  
    TreeNode node01 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.1", node0);  

    TreeNode node10 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 1.0", node1);  
    TreeNode node11 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 1.1", node1);  

    TreeNode node000 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.0.0", node00);  
    TreeNode node001 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.0.1", node00);  
    TreeNode node010 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 0.1.0", node01);  

    TreeNode node100 = new DefaultTreeNode("Node 1.0.0", node10);  
}  

public TreeNode getRoot() {  
    return root;  
}
```

here is the source of player.java

[Player.java](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/examples/trunk/showcase/src/main/java/org/primefaces/examples/domain/Player.java?r=3692)

**EDIT**

after looking at 
[Issue with p:tree inside loops (ui:repeat, p:dataTable, ...)](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=17460)

and

[Issue 3640:    NullPointerException during state saving with p:tree inside loops (ui:repeat, p:tabView, ...)](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=3640)

it seems that there is an open bug regarding this feature...

Comment: thank for your help.
i want to create in bean file, i tried
tmp.getChildren().add((UIComponent)root);
but can not.
please help me :)

Comment: Sorry... Haven't worked with Accordion/Tabs in that way... Unless there are strict requirements on implementation... You should try the example in the showcase...

Comment: so why we can create page in xhtml, can not in bean ?
thank :)

Comment: i want that because all infomation is dynamic, so components are dynamic :)

Comment: Cause using the tags such as <p:accordionPanel <p:tab and etc... in your xhtml page is the right way... under the hood its all being translated into the Objects... Its much easier and let concentrate on the business logic , and any way it the right way

Comment: have you looked at the example I posted ? the content is 100% dynamic the tabs are loaded from list

Comment: sorry, your example you post doesn't have dynamic tree in tab :)

Comment: I know , but the example can be easily expanded to match your case

Comment: Thank for your solution, but i still want to use like:
AccordionPanel TMPapMain = new AccordionPanel();
Tab tmp = new Tab();
TreeNode root = new  DefaultTreeNode("root",null);
TreeNode test = new DefaultTreeNode("test",root);           
tmp.getChildren().add((UIComponent)root);
TMPapMain.getChildren().add(tmp);
thank you very much :)

Comment: first start by running up the example from showcase on your local web app... afterwards add the feature i told you - I haven't tried it myself , but INMO it should work - of course i might be wrong , But I would have tried this solution before starting yours...

Comment: It works perfectly on the showcase, what your exact problem ? missing class like Player.java... what? You probably missed something....

Comment: i create simple tree in bean, it work.
i create AccordionPanel with text data, with dynamic tab, it work.
but when tree is a field in Player class, it doesn't work :-??

Comment: any exceptions? something in firebug?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.primefaces.component.api.UITree.findTreeNode(UITree.java:112)
 at org.primefaces.component.api.UITree.setRowKey(UITree.java:79)
 at org.primefaces.component.api.UITree.visitTree(UITree.java:408)
. . .

Comment: Bummer... it seems a bug in Primefaces... look here http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=17460 and open issue here http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=3640 , look at the first link I think there is some solution...